# intellij scene builder error not opening fxml file solved

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I have downloaded the latest scene builder from gloun, and I had my project settings done right. And yet I'm facing this error when i'm trying to open my fxml file

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.fxml.LoadListener PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, 192.6817.30] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@15d517ae

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader: com/sun/javafx/fxml/LoadListener [Plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX]
```

//edit: i installed choose runtime plugin, and ran jdk 1.8

Comment: intellij's embedded scene builder

Comment: this the first time i'm dealing with gui,,, i followed these instructions https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-fxml-files-in-javafx-scene-builder.html# and downloaded the latest version of scene builder... when i tried to open the fxml file, error occurs and it says "faild to open the file in the scene builder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here [Scene Builder does not work anymore after update to 2019.2 version](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004371099-Scene-Builder-does-not-work-anymore-after-update-to-2019-2-version), Scene Builder is not working properly with the new version of Intellij IDEA. Please use your Scene Builder as standalone app.